# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Κ (U+039A) polytonic greek and latin together

Tags: unicode

I've got several Unicode errors when compiling text with some greek text in polytonic characters inside mixed in various regions. I don't want to declare all de characters manually. Is there any way LaTeX can understand that is polytonic greek and rendering as my text editor already does?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
text text texttext text text
text text texttext text text
Κατάλογος etc. text text text
text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

I have spent the last hour looking at other questions but nothing works at the moment, using babel or utf8x etc. etc. I would like to avoid to but this text inside environments because is spread across all the text...

Comment: load greek with `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` and then mark the text up as greek, e.g. with `\ensuregreek{Κατάλογος}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks but  now I have all the text in greek

Comment: This happen when I use \usepackage[greek,italian]{babel} that is the command that I need

Comment: works fine for me with italian too (but you should then load \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

Comment: Strange with \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,italian]{report} did not work removing italian it worked

Comment: if you have `italian` in the class options, the second italian in babel is ignored and greek is the last and so main language.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In LuaLaTeX

The `babel` package in LuaLaTeX lets you auto-detect what script you’re typing in, and switch the font and hyphenation patterns you use accordingly.

The default font does not support Greek, so you need to pick one that does.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Load New Computer Modern
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}

\begin{document}
text text texttext text text
text text texttext text text
Κατάλογος etc. text text text
text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

There are fonts (such as the Computer Modern Unicode family) that need the `Script=Greek` OpenType feature to display actual Greek words correctly.  For these, you would want to set

```
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
```

This will set the `Script=` and `Language=` font features whenever you change languages.

### In PDFTeX

In a legacy engine, you have no choice but to use 8-bit fonts.  You also will need to tag your languages manually.  The `\textgreek` command is the most portable way to do this, and also shorter to type than `\foreignlangugae{greek.polutoniko}{Κατάλογος}`.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % Enable Greek encoding, but set Cork as the default.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage[greek.polutonic, main=italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
text text texttext text text
text text texttext text text
\textgreek{Κατάλογος} etc. text text text
text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Note that, per the manual, if you set `\documentclass[italian]`, you should also give `babel` the `main=italian` option.  Otherwise, `babel` will load Italian first, and set the main language to the last one it loaded, Greek.  I made the same mistake and got τεξτ all over the place.

You can also load `\usepackage{textalpha}` to be able to use `\textalpha`, `\textBeta`, and so on in text mode, or `\usepackage{alphabeta}` to be able to use `\alpha` and so on in text mode as well as math mode.